# Do you use "pick nits"?

Tags: idioms, expressions

Recently I have been watching **What's my car worth?**

One person said several times, "I like to pick nits.", as in being a nitpicker.

Do you use or have ever heard "pick nits"? It is used?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitpicking

Comment: Yah but does anyone actually say that?

Comment: Yeah, my boss often says, "I hate to pick nits, but..."

Comment: Not picking any nits but the point here is that an idiom is not to be rephrased or it ceases to be idiomatic. (I've done that just now to show how bad it can be. I could/should have said "Not nit-picking but...).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Nitpick*, *nit-pick*, and *pick nits* are all attested ([Thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com/browse/nitpick)). Literally it is the removal of the eggs of lice from the hair. Because the eggs are very small, this is a painstaking procedure.

Apparently the noun form *nit-picker* recently came to mean a person who attacks trivialities, and after that the verb form got its figurative sense ([World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-nit1.htm)).

Answer (score 4):

I think to the extent that Brits say it at all, it’s just a facetious reversal of metaphoric *nitpick* (occasionally hyphenated), which is really the only “standard” British version.

To me as a Brit, it’s a bit like saying, for example, “my flabber has never been so ghasted”.

But it seems [quite a few Americans](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nitpick,pick%20nits&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) (although still a minority) say it. I guess it’s unlikely they’re all doing it facetiously.

Comment: When I've heard this, I've taken it to mean the person wants to offer a little self-deprecation or small bit of humor before giving a criticism, so that the person might be receptive.

Comment: @Julia: I assume either you're not US-based, or the American usage is at least partly a regional thing. Many of the written American instances I linked to don't even seem to be self-conscious, let alone self-deprecating.

Comment: I am US-based.  Maybe even here it's a regional thing.  I've only heard it in a funny, exaggerated way, "I hate to pick a nit, but..." or "May I pick a nit?" (said with a British accent perhaps).  It stands out as trying to win over the listener in a small way.  I haven't seen it written - maybe it would seem different then.

Comment: Ooooo...! I like "My flabber has never been so ghasted"! My experience here in North America matches Juila's. Anyone who uses 'nit picker' when speaking of his or her self, is always using it in the sense that Julia described in her first comment.

Comment: As one who has (on occasion) been known to utter the phrase "pick nits", I can attest that @Julia is indeed correct: it's a bit of self-deprecation, because what comes after is likely to be annoying to those who don't care about details.

Comment: I can only repeat the info available from my link in the answer. To **pick nits** is so rare in Br. Eng. it's below the NGram radar. When I look at the American written examples, a significant proportion seem to use this form unselfconsciously, exactly the way we all use the far more common **pick holes**.

Comment: In my circles (in California), grammatically reinterpreting idioms is pretty commonplace.  I suppose it's a bit facetious, but so frequent that it's kind of just part of talking.  The "rule" that idioms should be used verbatim does not seem to hold here.